# NSURLSession в кнопке, долгий отклик

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, url, сессия

Создаю GET запрос при нажатии кнопки

NSLog(@"NO") и NSLog(@"YES") выводятся мгновенно при нажатии, весь дальнейший код выполняется только через ~40 секунд(вывод сообщение из полученного запроса, переход на другой экран), а переход на другой экран вообще падает, [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
- (IBAction)buttonConnect:(id)sender {
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:lineURLresult]; // URL
     NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
     dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
         id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
         if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] && error == nil){
             if([[object objectForKey:@"Success"] boolValue] == FALSE){
                 NSLog(@"NO");
                 _labelStatus.text = [object objectForKey:@"Message"];
             }
             else {
                 NSLog(@"True");
                 _labelStatus.text = @"YES";
                 // Переход на VievControllerTable
                 ViewControllerTable *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerTable"];
                 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
             }
         }
     }];
    [downloadTask resume];
}
```

При NSURLConnection таких проблем нет

```
- (IBAction)buttonConnect:(id)sender {
// создаем запрос
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:lineURLresult]
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:15.0];

    // создаём соединение и начинаем загрузку
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if (connection) {
        // соединение началось
        _labelStatus.text = @"Подключение...";
        // создаем NSMutableData, чтобы сохранить полученные данные
        receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    } else {
        // при попытке соединиться произошла ошибка
        _labelStatus.text = @"Произошла ошибка!";
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
// получен ответ от сервера
[receivedData setLength:0];
}

 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
// добавляем новые данные к receivedData
[receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
// выводим сообщение об ошибке
NSString *errorString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Ошибка подключения"];
_labelStatus.text = errorString;
}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
// Результат подключения
NSError *error = nil;
id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
if([[object objectForKey:@"Success"] boolValue] == FALSE)
    _labelStatus.text = [object objectForKey:@"Message"];
else {
    _labelStatus.text = @"";

    // Сохранение
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:self.lineNameProfile forKey:@"lineNameProfile"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:self.linePassword forKey:@"linePassword"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    // Переход на VievControllerTable
    ViewControllerTable *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerTable"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить Вам несколько вариантов решения данной проблемы:

1) `completion handler` должен быть в `Main thread`, для этого можно использовать метод `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`

2) Можно использовать библиотеку [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

Пример:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:yourURL parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
  NSLog(@"SUCCESS");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
  NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

3) Обновление `UI` всегда должно быть в `main thread`, иначе обновление может занять около минуты. Поместите код связанный с `UI` в блок:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
 // обновление UI
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал использовать другой подход, я думаю что это решит проблему.

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

[[session dataTaskWithUrl:url
        completionHandler:^(NSData *_Nullable data, NSURLResponse *_Nullable response, NSError *_Nullable error) {
               /* your code in callback (response) here */
           }] resume];
```

Работать с callback (completionHandler) в главном потоке **нельзя**, так как он остановит работу приложения и будет выполнять код **синхронно**.

Работа с UI (изменение текста UITextField) должна быть асинхронна в главном потоке, для этого используем внутри completionHandler вот это:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                /* your UI updates here */
            });
```

В конечном итоге у нас получится вот такая история:

```
[[session dataTaskWithUrl:url
       completionHandler:^(NSData *_Nullable data, NSURLResponse *_Nullable response, NSError *_Nullable error) {
               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                _labelStatus.text = parsedString;
            });
           }] resume];
```